# Trying to include carousel with a timer in javafx

Tags: javafx

Trying to include carousel with a timer in javafx.

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageslidder;
    @FXML
    private ImageView left;
    @FXML
    private ImageView right;
    @FXML
    private Circle picone;
    @FXML
    private Circle pictwo;
    @FXML
    private Circle picthree;
    int imag_index = 0;
    String images[] = new String []{"sample/one.jpg", "sample/two.jpg", "sample/three.jpg"};
    void nextImage() {
        switch (imag_index) {
            case 0:
                setStroke(picone);
                resetStroke(pictwo);
                resetStroke(picthree);
                break;
            case 1:
                setStroke(pictwo);
                resetStroke(picone);
                resetStroke(picthree);
                break;
            case 2:
                setStroke(picthree);
                resetStroke(pictwo);
                resetStroke(picone);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        imag_index++;
        if (imag_index == images.length) ;
        {
            imag_index = 0;

        }
        try {
            String imagpath = getClass().getResource(images[imag_index]).toURI().toString();
            Image img = new Image(imagpath);
            imageslidder.setImage(img);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    void prevImage() {
        nextImage();

    }

    void setStroke(Circle indicator) {
        indicator.setFill(Paint.valueOf("#03a9f4"));
        indicator.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("#cddc39"));
        indicator.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        indicator.setStrokeWidth(5);


    }

    void resetStroke(Circle indicator) {
        indicator.setFill(Paint.valueOf("ffffff"));
        indicator.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("#1e90ff"));
        indicator.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        indicator.setStrokeWidth(1);


    }


    public void initializer(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: What is the error/issue you are looking for help with.

Comment: the images are not displaying. But no error when I run it.